# How to fix this forEach function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this forEach function but it doesn't work :

```
arr =  [ 0, 50, 0, 14]
```

basicly I want to use the values of the array to use in nested for loop like this :

```
arr.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
    for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
        for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
            doSomething(x,y) 
        } 
    } 
});
```

could you tell me why ? and how to fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: What are your trying to do here? If you want to create 4 variables, you don't need forEach. You can use destructuring like this: `let [myx1, myx2, myx3, myx4] = arr`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach first.

Comment: Seems you might not understand how forEach works. At the first pass, it uses the first value and passes that into the function, then a second pass with the second value, etc. While the full array is available within the forEach handler function, it is intended to act on single members.

Comment: basicly I want to use the values of the array to use in nested for loop like this : arr.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
        for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
            for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
                doSomething(x,y)
            }
        }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using forEach as it would iterate the array. For your usecase you could use array destructuring.

```js
let arr = [0, 50, 0, 14];
let [x1, x2, y1, y2] = arr;
for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
    for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
        doSomething(x,y) 
    } 
}
```

More on Destructuring assignment here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Your forEach didn't work as you are expecting all four elements to be returned in a single iteration so for your forEach to work like the way you mentioned you should enclose the array of elements in another array like

```js
let arr = [[0, 50, 0, 14]];
arr.forEach(([x1, x2, y1, y2]) => {
    for (let x = x1; x < x2; ++x) {
        for (let y = y1; y < y2; ++y) {
            doSomething(x,y) 
        } 
    } 
});
```

It would work now as you are now destructuring the first item of the array which is the array containing four elements. What it means is that you are taking arr[0] which is [0, 50, 0, 14] and assigning it to [x1, x2, y1, y2] using destructuring. It is same as

```js
arr.forEach(item => {
    const [x1, x2, y1, y2] = item
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to convert the array to an object.

```
const obj = {
    myx1: arr[0],
    myx2: arr[1],
    myy1: arr[2],
    myy2: arr[3],
}
```

there is no need for a loop in your case.

Comment: You did not consider the OP's requirment

Comment: @RohitKashyap he didnt gave an requirements, at least at the point of writing this